# Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.CommandUnknownException: No executable found matching command "dotnet-migrations"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a migration to a project that uses Entity framework 2.1.4.
I've been editing the files by hand, but was told the following was the right way:

Running 'dotnet -d migrations add test -c OurContext' but, it gives me the error:

dotnet : Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.CommandUnknownException: No executable found matching command "dotnet-migrations"

It won't let me delete this question, but the answer was that the person who gave me the command left out the 'ef' in the command.  (thanks for the down vote whomever did good grief)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `dotnet ef migrations`. You left out the `ef` part. The actual global tool is `dotnet-ef`, when you just have `dotnet migrations`, it's looking for a `dotnet-migrations` global tool, which is not a thing.

Comment: I should clarify the above comment (which I can't edit), the 'That worked..' was your fix of adding the 'ef' to it, that I had no way of know was supposed to be in the command.. (not what someone else sent me... they sent me the command w/o it..)